# Target specific content in jekyll layout

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to think how to achieve this in jekyll:

- I've got a multi column layout in mind
- But want to keep my content for the page in one file
- So how do I target content to each column?

Is there any way to qualify content through selectors? e.g. {{content.col1}} {{content.col2}}

The only other way I can think around the problem is move some of the content up to the YAML front matter and split it up that way - but not ideal.

Thanks

Comment: You have some content (e.g. various lists) and want to show them in multiple columns? Why you don't create or use a CSS multi-column layout and put content in each column? For example, you can create one `<div>` for each column and put what you want in this specific column in there.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm caught where is best place to put content - as markdown or in the yaml. It's for a retail site and really so that authors who aren't web savvy have a place to edit product data : name, description, cost etc without worrying about editing actual HTML markup.